# Inputing accented letters in Qt applications on Cygwin

Tags: x11, cygwin, input, qt, xinput

I am a native Portuguese speaker, and I am having problems when typing accented characters in any Qt application running on Cygwin.

Almost always, the result on the screen for any accented letter I type is the `�` character (Unicode's *Replacement Character*, u+fffd).

I believe that the problem is related to interpreting the keyboard input, and not with displaying characters.  More specifically, that problem seems to be with the resulting input of combining key sequences, such as dead-tilde plus `a` to get an `ã` or dead-acute plus `e` to get an `é`; I don't have problems when I use `cat` in a Qt-based terminal emulator to display a file containing accented characters on screen, nor with the copying/pasting text with accents from another source, nor with any symbol that results from a single keystroke (such as `ç`, that has its own key on a Brazilian ABNT2 keyboard, or any other non-combining symbol produced from any key while holding *AltGr* modifier key). Also, if I type anything on the terminal (either *konsole* or *qterminal*) directly into `hexdump -C`, it is clear that the terminal (or some underlying library) is delivering the 3-byte UTF-8 sequence `"\xef\xbf\xbd"`, which corresponds to u+fffd, as mentioned above.

I also believe that it is a Qt-related problem because GTK-based applications, such as Gnome Terminal or LXTerminal, don't suffer from it.

Another thing that I already tried was changing locales before starting Qt applications and the X11 server itself, and it didn't help.

So my question are:

1. How to configure my Cygwin environment so that Qt understands accented letters (and perhaps any other Unicode symbol resulting from combining multiple key sequences)?
2. Do I have to install and configure any specific X11 input library in order to have Qt working properly? I'm not acquainted with Qt dependencies for handling input, so any help would greatly appreciated, and taken note of.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In theory Cygwingis using UTF8, if not different LANG is specified. So which application ? I can copy and paste ã from Windows charmap to Octave Gui that is a QT5 application.

Comment: @matzeri, I didn't install many Qt applications this time, but I always try at least ```konsole``` and ```qterminal```. As mentioned above, the problem is only when typing, not when pasting, but since Portuguese is my mother tongue, I'd like to be able to use it with Qt applications on Cygwin, just as I do on Linux.

Comment: If the problem is also present in `Xterm` and not only in `Konsole` than see : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Configuring_compose_key